# od command to print all the values

Tags: od

I am running the od command as `od -b myfile` to convert a file I have into image pixels. I need to see all the values but because they are too many the command prints the following:

```
0000000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
*
1130000
```

Is there any way to get all my values instead of just the first and the last?

Comment: You can use the `-v` option to suppress the duplicate lines. See also https://superuser.com/questions/494245/what-does-an-asterisk-mean-in-hexdump-output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `-v` option: this tells `od` to output duplicate lines (which it normally suppresses). So

```
od -v -b myfile
```

will produce the output you’re after.